# CodeIgniter send Email with outlook.com

Tags: codeigniter, email, ssl, outlook.com

I am trying to send emails using CodeIgniter and *outlook.com* (using XAMPP).

Sending emails using Codeigniter and *Gmail* worked well, using the following `$config` specifications:

```
$config = array(
  'mailtype' => 'html'
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'smtp_user' => '******@gmail.com',
  'smtp_pass' => '******'
);
```

However, applying the following *outlook.com* config specifications results in error messages (see below):

```
$config = array(
  'mailtype' => 'html'
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.live.com',
  'smtp_port' => 587,
  'smtp_user' => '******@outlook.com',
  'smtp_pass' => '******'
);
```

Errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:     error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.live.com:587 (Unknown error)
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

Replacing 'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.live.com' with 'tls://smtp.live.com' results in the following error messages:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1689

[etc.]
```

**Question:**
Which specifications do I need to apply in order to get Codeigniter Email to work with outlook.com?

Comment: smtp_user in your outlook settings has gmail.com in it which is invalid.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, ahmad! Copy/past mistake corrected. However, the problem remains the same. Any advice?

Comment: Try removing ssl:// from the hostname & set the option smtp_crypto to "tls"